# SELECT for an array field -- Magento

Tags: php, sql, magento

One of the fields in my seller db has following data:

```
{"delivery area":"delivery amount"}
```

An example of this data in the db is as follows:

```
{"1":"0","2":"0","3":"0","4":"200","5":"1"}
```

Now I want to write a query that picks all sellers that deliver to a particular delivery area.

How can I do it using SQL? What do I specify in the WHERE clause?

I am working on Magento so an equivalent in addFieldToFilter will also help.

Comment: can you post the current SQL code you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this value is nothing but a json encoded value. All I had to do was to decode it upon reading and extract the values.